# Apache Commons ToStringBuilder String encoding

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

I'm using Apache Commons' ToStringBuilder to generate entities toString's block content.
But for some entities, there are String fields encoded with "ISO-8859-15", so I'm wondering if the produced toString will use platform's default (UTF-8 on my vm) with values outputed incorrectly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: Yeap, it was a good reminder, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java strings are **always** using *Unicode* for characters.

Encoding **only** becomes an issue when reading/writing strings from/to files. Or when converting strings into byte arrays for example.

In that sense: you do not have to worry about the string builder. You have to worry about "where are is the data initially coming from" respectively "going to".

Just for completeness: yes, the Java String class has a constructor where you can pass in the desired **encoding** - but that constructor *also* takes an array of bytes as first argument. And as said: in such cases you have to worry about encoding.